# Create trigger that delete after insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a trigger that delete any new row I insert if the value is more than a number, for example 8.

I tried this:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER INSERT ON mytab
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM mytab WHERE myparameter > 8;
    END
|

DELIMITER ;
```

I tried to:

```
INSERT INTO mytab VALUES (9);
```

and this is the message error:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'mytab' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

also if I put:

```
INSERT INTO mytab VALUES (4);
```

it runs the same error...

Thanks!

Comment: you can not do insert/update/delete on the same table where you are running the trigger.

Comment: What is wrong? You need to give more info: the error message would be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't delete!  Just produce an error on the insert:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON mytab
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        IF new.myparameter > 8 THEN
             signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Parameter value can be no larger than 8';
        END IF;
    END
|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You haven't erase the line of delete :P Thanks a lot Gordon!!